# ODE particular solution confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been having trouble with making correct guesses on particular solutions. More specifically on this question: $y''-4y'+4y=12e^{2t}$ , which is example one on this page [https://math.jhu.edu/~brown/courses/f18/ExampleProblems/UndetCoeffBadGuesses.pdf](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Ebrown/courses/f18/ExampleProblems/UndetCoeffBadGuesses.pdf).

The correct guess used is $Y(t)=At^2e^{2t}$ , when I thought it would be $Ae^{2t}$.

However, on Paul's online notes, a problem done is $y′′−4y′−12y=3e^{5t}$, and the correct guess IS $Ae^{5t}$.

Why is this? Is it dependent on the complementary solution? Or is there any shortcut/process to knowing how to correct a guess when wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The notes mention $Ae^{2t}$ is not a good guess since it is a solution to the homogeneous equation

Comment: In the first DE $e^{2t}$  (and also $te^{2t}$) is already a solution to the homogeneous differential equation. Paul's DE is different in this. The correct process is to solve first the homogeneous DE then guess the particular solution.